# How to reverse geocode with ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

What steps to I have to take in ArcMap (ArcEditor) to input a lat / long and return nearest address?

I found the Reverse Geocode tool but I can't figure out what to put in the "Input Features" and "Output Feature Class" fields or where to input my lat / long.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Reverse Geocode Tool Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002600000009000000.htm).

Your data needs to be in a format that ArcGIS will recognize as a layer (shapefile, geodatabase feature class, etc.). If you just have XY's in a table, consider adding your table to ArcMap then using the [add XY data tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000001z000000.htm) to create a layer you can use in the reverse geocode tool.

Comment: This tool also works with the Esri World Geocode service, just sign into ArcGIS ONline from ArcMap, browse to the Esri Ready to use services, Geocode Tools, World Address Locator and bingo.  Will use credits from your ArcGIS Online subscription

Answer (score 2):

I was actually looking for this: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00250000002n000000.htm