# Assigning point order (traffic signals) based on location on lines (bus routes) in another layer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, linear-referencing

I need to list all signalized intersections a bus route passes through, in order. I have both the intersection locations and the bus routes visualized in ArcMap.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6476/finding-distance-of-point-along-polyline-using-arcgis-desktop of any help?